# kiosk mode buster lite Pi Br2

Tags: pi-2, raspicam, kiosk, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am trying to view my Octopi PiCam on a PiB2. I followed the guide here: https://die-antwort.eu/techblog/2017-12-setup-raspberry-pi-for-kiosk-mode/

Everything has went fine, no errors, no crashes. Yet when I startx I only get a blank screen. I noticed I could change desktops (all blank), but no cam view.

Accessing using OctoPi.local:8080/?action=stream on another pi shows the webcam as expected.